# Android NDK: Invalid APP_STL value: c++_static

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I try to compile Cococs2d-x android projects ...

```
$ cd /Users/ahmadayman/Documents/games/game01/proj.android
$ python ./build_native.py
```

And i got the following error!

```
The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
Android NDK: Invalid APP_STL value: c++_static  

Android NDK: Please use one of the following instead:  system stlport_static stlport_shared gnustl_static gnustl_shared gabi++_static gabi++_shared none 

make: Entering directory `/Users/ahmadayman/Documents/games/game01/proj.android'
/Users/ahmadayman/android-ndk-r9/build/core/add-application.mk:254: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

make: Leaving directory `/Users/ahmadayman/Documents/games/game01/proj.android'
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./build_native.py", line 159, in <module>
build(opts.ndk_build_param,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
File "./build_native.py", line 146, in build
do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
File "./build_native.py", line 82, in do_build
raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ 
/Users/ahmadayman/Documents/games/game01/proj.android ] fails!
```

And also when i run this command...

```
$ ndk-build
Android NDK: Invalid APP_STL value: c++_static    
Android NDK: Please use one of the following instead:  system stlport_static stlport_shared gnustl_static gnustl_shared gabi++_static gabi++_shared none    
/Users/ahmadayman/android-ndk-r9/build/core/add-application.mk:254: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

Comment: I used `gnustl_static` with `NDK-r9b` in Cocos2dx-3.2 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a newer NDK release, NDK r9 didn't provide libc++_static, that's why it's not a valid value in your Application.mk